# Why do I need to override a pure virtual function if it's provided by another base class?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

The following will not compile:

```
struct A
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct B
{
    virtual void foo() {}
};

struct C : A, B
{
    using B::foo;
};

C c;
```

C++ considers `C` an abstract class because it failed to directly override the pure virtual `foo`. What's the rationale behind this? I can, of course, throw an exception in `A::foo` instead of making it a pure virtual but is there a better design pattern?

Comment: Even if you throw an exception in `A::foo`, this will not work - `c.B::foo()` and `c.A::foo()` are different functions. The name of the methods does not matter here, you need to create a custom method in `C`, `C::foo`,  that call `B::foo`.

Comment: Above code should not compile (and does not with clang

Comment: Strangely (or not), the code is almost identical to that in the dupe ...

Comment: Holt, you're right. It compiles with the exception but
A* p = new C;
p->foo();
calls A::foo rather than B::foo
Wow, I really misunderstood how this worked. Thanks for clarifying it for me.